# Migrar proyecto SSIS con Visual Studio 2017 para abrirlo con Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ssis

Hemos desarrollado un proyecto de ETL con Visual Studio 2017 (modelo de implementación de paquetes) con destino para SQL Server 2012. Queremos poder editarlo con Visual Studio 2010, que es la herramienta que originalmente utilizábamos.

He intentado varias formas pero no lo he conseguido. La última ha sido intentar importar desde un proyecto creado con Visual Studio 2010 una ETL creada con Visual Studio 2017 y aparecen estos errores:

- El número de versión del paquete no es válido. El número de versión no puede ser mayor que el número de versión actual.
- Error al migrar el paquete de la versión 8 a la versión 6: 0xC001700A "El número de versión del paquete no es válido. El número de versión no puede ser mayor que el número de versión actual.".

Desde Visual Studio 2017 hemos podido abrir y editar proyectos creados con Visual Studio 2010 y después no hemos tenido problemas en volver a editarlos con Visual Studio 2010. Por esto espero que sea posible el camino inverso.

Muchas gracias por adelantado,

Answer (score 1):

Mi respondo yo mismo a la pregunta. No, no se puede migrar un proyecto SSIS que creado inicialmente con VS2017 para abrirlo con VS2010. El formato de los paquetes (ficheros .DTSX) es diferente.

En [este enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24770237-0889-422f-a697-ab514496e681/errorpackage-migration-from-version-8-to-version-6-failed-with-error-0xc001700a?forum=sqlintegrationservices) de un foro de Microsoft plantean una pregunta similar y en la primera respuesta aparece la explicación.

También he encontrado [esta otra página](http://blog.josemarianoalvarez.com/2017/12/12/la-version-paquete-ssis-integration-services/) dónde se detalla las distintas versiones de los paquetes en relación a los SQL Server y las herramientas de edición.

La solución que hemos tomado ha sido crear un proyecto desde cero con VS2010 e implementar de nuevo las ETL. De este modo ese proyecto se puede editar también con VS2017 y después volverlo a editar con VS2010 porque no se modifica la versión de los paquetes DTSX.